# Strange function surprisingly well behaved

Tags: number-theory

Define $P_n(x)$ to be the polynomial $(x-p_1)(x-p_2)\dots(x-p_i)=0$ where $p_i$ runs through the prime factors of $n$, with multiplicity, and let

$$g(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{-1}^{0} P_k(x) \,dx$$

$g(n)$ seems very nicely behaved:

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[With[{a = FactorInteger[#]}, 
Integrate[Times @@ (x + Flatten[-ConstantArray[#, #2] & @@ # & /@ a]), 
{x, -1, 0}]] & /@ Range@#]/Range@# &@10000, PlotRange -> All]
```

With such wild polynomials, what is going on with the regularity in oscillations between $\approx \pm \sqrt{n}?$

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose to define $g(x)$ in this way? For instance, as opposed to integrating over a different interval?

Comment: If you really mean the product over the prime factors of $x$, then $P(x)$ is not a polynomial. What does $x_i$ mean in the definition of $g(x)$? (In general it's very strange to use $x$ to denote a natural number; it would be more standard / readable to use $n$ or $k$. And personally I would use $p_i$ to denote a bunch of primes.)

Comment: The prime factors of $x$, and just after you integrate $P(x_i)$ ? It doesn't mean anything

Comment: @mixedmath the interval seems well behaved between any fixed constants

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'll have a go at renotating

Comment: What's $x_i$ here anyway?

Comment: @reuns $=0$ added - hope makes sense now - if not will continue to work on clarifying

Comment: You didn't clarify anything. Did you mean $P(n) = \prod_{p | n} (n-p)$ ?

Comment: @Ian fixed now - silly mistake

Comment: I still don't understand your definitions. You have an integral sign there; what variable are you integrating with respect to? $P(i)$ (whose definition I also don't understand, as it's still not a polynomial as written) as written is just a number, not a function.

Comment: @reuns yes, but before I update, each prime is distinct - how can I clarify that?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes - that's it will update - thanks

Comment: The notation reuns used already means "$p$ runs over all the primes which divide $n$ (once each)," so that doesn't need to be clarified. If that's what $P$ is then I remain confused about what the integral in the definition of $g$ means.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, it's just a number - a numerical value in the interval $[-1,0]$ - I don't really know how else to describe it

Comment: Then what does $\int_{-1}^0$ mean? The integral of a number from $-1$ to $0$ is just that number again. I am still very confused. Can you tell me how you would calculate, say, $g(6)$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $\int_{-1}^0 (x-1) \, dx+\int_{-1}^0 (x-2) \, dx+\int_{-1}^0 (x-3) \, dx+\int_{-1}^0 (x-2)^2 \, dx+\int_{-1}^0 (x-5) \, dx+\int_{-1}^0 (x-2)(x-3) \, dx$

Comment: Okay, so it's the thing I said in the comment I deleted, I guess. (It is *definitely* not what you've currently written.) I'll edit your post to what I think you're trying to say. What's the deal with the $\int_{-1}^0 (x - 2)^2 \, dx$ term? I thought you said you only wanted distinct prime factors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ah, no - not distinct - prime factors with multiplicity

Comment: Okay, great, I think I finally understand your definition. I edited the body to be what I think it currently is. Your polynomial was a polynomial in a variable $x$ but it also depended on a second integer parameter $n$, which it seems like you were conflating. This is one reason, among others, why it is very confusing to use $x$ to denote an integer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks for your help :) I'll remember not to use $x$!

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic answer.

If $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$  is a Dirichlet series related to $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)},\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}, \log \zeta(s)$ ie. encoding the Riemann hypothesis in the asymptotics for $\sum_{n \le x} a_n, x \to \infty$,

then $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-nx}$ encodes the Riemann hypothesis in the asymptotics for $f(x), x \to 0^+$

In particular the RH is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) e^{-nx} = \mathcal{O}(x^{-1/2-\epsilon})$.

The main reason to that is $F(s) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x) x^{s-1}dx$.

Here it seems you are looking at $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{p | n} (e^{-x}-p) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-x \omega(n)} \sum_{d | \text{rad}(n)} d e^{\omega(d)}$ which has good chances to encode the RH.